# addListeners() not working correctly in a screen is inside a tab that's nested in a stack React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation library for my application with the following structure:

```
const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootTabParamList>();

    <NavigationContainer theme={appTheme}>
        <RootStack.Navigator>
              <RootStack.Screen name="Tabs" component={Tabs}/>
              <RootStack.Screen name="Screen A" />
              <RootStack.Screen name="Screen B"/>
              <RootStack.Screen name="Screen C"/>
        </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Tabs is a functional component that renders anothor Navigator like this:

```
<Tab.Navigator>
     <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
     <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
     <Tab.Screen name="Exit" component={Exit} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

When I press tab Exit I want to listen to 'tabPress' event to handle my logic. So following the document of React Navigation, in my Exit component I did that:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    return props.navigation.addListener('tabPress', (e) => {
      console.log('Doing something when tabPress');
    });
  }, [props.navigation]);
```

Document link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#events

But I didn't get the desired result. The log line is not printed.

What's the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the `tabPress` event like this.

```
 <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} 
    listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
      tabPress: (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Doing something when tabPress');
      },
    })}
 />
```

Comment: I tried it and it works like a charm. But I wonder why `addListener()` is not working?

Answer (score 0):

don't use the function in cleanup. it should be like this.
cleanup only runs when component unmounts.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('tabPress', (e) => {
      console.log('Doing something when tabPress');
    });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [props.navigation]);
```

Comment: I have tried it but It still not working!

Comment: if you have a custom tab bar, make sure to emit this event.

Comment: I don't have a custom tab bar. I create my tab bar by using createBottomTabNavigator()